# Proper style in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

What should be the proper "style" of biblatex package for this type of bibliography?[image]

"authoryear-ibid" style is producing similar, but not exactly the same result.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The image of your desired output isn't especially helpful. It also underdetermines the format of certain reference types. Perhaps you could post a compilable example document using `author-year` and then explain which parts of the formatting you want to change. It's likely that most of the changes have been covered by other questions on the site.

Comment: As a start, please see this question: [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806)

Answer (score 1):

From a screenshot alone it is hard to implement a full bibliography and citation style, but I feel that asking for a full style is too much for one question here anyway. Since `biblatex` is quite easily configured and still fairly young, there are not that many ready-made styles available on CTAN (compared to BibTeX). If your style is not one of the big (APA, Chicago, IEEE, Nature, ...) styles for which an implementation exists already, you will have to start from a similar style and do the rest yourself. To that end it is much more useful for other users if you can isolate the important characteristics of your style and ask about each one separately. I'm quite confident that you can find answers to many of those questions already. A good start is always [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864).

Here is a start that addresses the most important aspects of the style as shown in the screenshot (as I see them). I used [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext)'s version of `authoryear-ibid` as basis, because it makes a few things easier (namely `articlein` as well as `\jourvoldelim` and `\volnumdelim`).

```latex
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-ibid,
  articlein=false,
  giveninits=true, maxbibnames=6, minbibnames=6,]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space\&\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,aksin,nussbaum,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Aksın, Ö., Türkmen, H., Artok, L., Çetinkaya, B., Ni, C., Büyükgüngör, O. et al. (2006). Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions. J. Organomet. Chem. 691(13), 3027–3036.//Geer, I. de (1985). Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet.//Nussbaum, M. (1978). Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’. Princeton: Princeton University Press.//Sigfridsson, E., & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Worman, N. (2002). The Cast of Character. Style in Greek Literature. Austin: University of Texas Press.]