# Which package will allow me to reference as shown in the image?

Tags: biblatex, natbib

I wish to construct the references in my dissertation according to the attached screenshot. Trouble is, after hours of trying, I can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have an idea if this is even possible?

[image]

The closest style I can find is also on the cite it right website.

Comment: The requested style seems to be close the `authoryear` bibliography style from `biblatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to write a complete style from one example alone and this site is not really suited for questions like this anyway, it is much better to ask about specific features of your style separately.

Here is something to get you started. I used `biblatex-ext` as a basis in order to have easier access to a few more customisations.

Most command names should hopefully be self-explanatory, but you may still want to look up details in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

A good introduction to `biblatex` styles is [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864), some specific questions for your style would be

- [Suppress "In:" biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10682/35864)
- [How do I get "et al." to appear in italics when using \textcite or \citeauthor with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40798/35864)

A similar style is discussed in [Proper style in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/493233/35864).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear,
  maxbibnames=999,
  giveninits, uniquename=init,
  articlein=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  andothers = {\mkbibemph{et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{yoon}
dolor \autocite{worman}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. (1998) ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’, Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), pp. 377–395, doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: That's very helpful of you. Thank you. I can't seem to get your supplied code to work though. I get an error at the \renewcommand lines

Comment: @H98 Do you maybe get an error even earlier? Does your system even have `biblatex-ext` installed?

Comment: @H98 Or to make this more useful: Run the MWE from this answer in a new, empty folder. Compile it with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX as usual (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). If there are any errors only look at the first error message you get (the following errors can be knock-on effects and are often sorted out by dealing with the actual cause of the first error). What does it say? Then skim the other error messages. What do they say?

Comment: Hi sorry, I re ran it and it worked. Thank you so much