# Using makebst to generate styles

Tags: custom-bib

Okay so I want to make a referencing style which matches the attached as closely as possible. Is this doable with makebst?

Additionally, how safe is it to use MikTex in conjunction with texlive? I had to install the latter since MikTex freaked out on me.

[image]

The closest style I can find is also on the cite it right website.

Comment: Since you specifically ask about `makebst` I have retagged your question. The `.bst` files generated by `makebst` can not be used with `biblatex` at all (and we already have a `biblatex` version of the question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510170/35864). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864.

Comment: Re your question on whether it is safe to use MikTeX in conjunction with TeX live: The systems should be set up in a way that you can only use one at a time and so that they are completely separate and don't interfere with each other. Then it should be save to have both, but you will only ever use one of the two systems at any given time. If you are only ever going to use the same system it may make sense to uninstall the other to avoid confusion.

Comment: What about online sources. Is there a way to add (online) to my references?